# Writing char[] to file using nio

Tags: java, nio

I am generating a text to save like that:

```
private static final int iloscliczb = 1000;
static char[] znaki = new char[iloscliczb];

private static void generujZnaki() {
    int i;

        for (i=0;i<iloscliczb;i++)
    {
        znaki[i]= (char) (97 + r.nextInt(35));
    }

}
```

And now I want to save it to text file using java NIO - I looked over and over again and I have problem... I done it already using java.io and now I want to do this using java.nio but everything I found is for String and it does not allow me to save my char's array to a file...

Comment: You can convert your `char[]` to `String` with `new String(znaki)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for the String class, you will see that it implements an interface for a sequence of character arrays. Thus, creating a string from a character array should not be a problem because they are derived from the same code.

```
String znakiString = new String(znaki);
```